# New site functionality makes my cursor disappear

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro

The new functionality which displays the count of questions with new activity seems to cause my cursor arrow to disappear using Firefox 10.0.2 on Mac OS 10.6.8. Reloading the page, sometimes solves the problem, but it's not reliable.  Reloading a non SE tab, however, does seem to bring back the arrow.

Can anyone confirm this behaviour?

Comment: You are lucky: I don't even see the new activity banner. `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have been collecting cursor arrows for charity - we figured since you weren't using yours all of the time we could borrow it.  Don't worry - it's for a good cause.

Seriously though, We don't have any code that controls the visibility of the cursor.

Comment: Well I'm just glad it's going to a good cause. The problem hasn't shown up for a bit, and I can't reliably reproduce it. If it does and I can, I'll update the question. It showed up right when the new functionality did, but maybe it was just a coincidence.